# Boolean short circuit

Tags: jexl

Jexl already supports boolean short circuiting
Expression = A || B
if A = True, B doesn't have to be set.

However if A = False and B is not set, the evaluation throws JexlException exception - undefined variable B.

The use case is to lazily evaluate B.
Is there a clean way to find out if the expression can be short circuited with what variables value we know currently?
Is handling JexlException and then proceeding to evaluate B right way?

Comment: private String getNextVariableToEvaluate(){
 try {
            expression.evaluate(context);
        } catch (JexlException.Variable jexl) {
            return jexl.getVariable();
        }
 return null;       
}

Intiatially if expression is {A || B && C} and we have A as true, the above will return C.
However, if A is False, this will return B and we will then evaluate B.

SO, I am trying to use the evaluate method [which has short-circuit], to find out which variable to evaluate lazily.

But this has a cost due to exception stack trace.

Comment: Is there another clean way to get the next variable to lazily evaluate without the costly exceptions?

Comment: I don't understand the question enough to provide an answer, but I suspect your "context" just MapContext and you don't want to populate it with more variables than you need to evaluate expression.  JexlExpression.evaluate() accepts a JexlContext so you could implement your own JexlContext to lazily provide (and cache) variables in the "get" and "has" methods.